# Using .pop in Python

Tags: python

Likely a very simple question.   I'm trying to get the other attributes and I think i'm having issues with the object type.  I'm getting no values when running the "Desired" code.  Thanks for your help.

```
SSNs = pd.read_excel("{0}/Test.xlsx".format(file_path))

In[29]:SSNs.columns.values
Out[29]: 
array(['SSN', 'Last_Name', 'First_Name', 'Group'], dtype=object)
```

Current and working:

```
Fizz = list(SSNs.loc[SSNs.Group== 'Fizz','SSN'])
Buzz = list(SSNs.loc[SSNs.Group== 'Buzz','SSN'])
In[30]:Fizz.pop()
Out[30]: '1111111111'
```

Desired:

```
Fizz = list(SSNs.loc[SSNs.Group== 'Fizz',['SSN','Last_Name','First_Name']])
Buzz = list(SSNs.loc[SSNs.Scrd_Tier == 'Buzz',['SSN','Last_Name','First_Name']])
In[30]:Fizz.pop()
Out[30]: ['1111111111','Bob','Knight']
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. Without any example data how can we help?

Answer (score 1):

Working through the documentation..

Fake data:

```
In [58]: d
Out[58]: {'a': (1, 4, 7, 1), 'b': (2, 5, 8, 'z'), 'c': (3, 6, 9, 'z')}
In [59]: df = pd.DataFrame(d)
In [60]: df
Out[60]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9
3  1  z  z
```

Condition:

```
In [61]: df.a == 1
Out[61]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Selecting row(s):

```
In [63]: z = df.loc[df.a == 1, ['a','b','c']]
In [64]: z
Out[64]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3
3  1  z  z
```

Data:

```
In [75]: values = z.values
In [76]: values
Out[76]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 'z', 'z']], dtype=object)
```

Data (numpy ndarray) --> list

```
In [83]: as_list = map(list, values)
In [84]: as_list
Out[84]: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 'z', 'z']]
```

Or `[list(row) for row in values]` instead of `map(...)`

**pop**

```
In [85]: as_list.pop()
Out[85]: [1, 'z', 'z']
In [86]: as_list.pop()
Out[86]: [1, 2, 3]
```

---

You may want to spend some time with this: ["Pandas From The Ground Up" talk](http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015)